# Return to Search result page

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, web, asp.net-ajax

I stuck with Problem where I have to return to previous page without posting it back to server, Like Gmail, where we can search for an email which list the bunch of emails and you open one and then click "back to results" button and you are back to search results page without server postback. I honestly don't have any idea how does this work, but if anybody could guide me the right path, would be great.
When I was googling, I came across few techniques like

1. Caching the particular page
2. simulate the browsers back button (it cause postback for me)

If the explanation with ASP.NET context would be great.

Answer (score 0):

May be some of these links will help

[How do you prevent "browser history polution?](http://forums.asp.net/t/942954.aspx?How%20do%20you%20prevent%20browser%20history%20polution%20)

One of the possible solitions

[Stop ASP.NET PostBacks Showing As Separate Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797004/stop-asp-net-postbacks-showing-as-separate-pages)

[Disable the Browser Back Button in your ASP.NET Applications](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/defeat-the-evil-back-button-in-your-asp-net-applications/)

Comment: All these seems to disable the browser history but i want to preserve the last page and serve it back without postback